# What happened to Solidarity?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, infectious-diseases, who-world-health-org

Solidarity is a large clinical trial of treatment candidates for COVID–19, organised by the World Health Organisation (WHO). The [relevant page](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/global-research-on-novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov/solidarity-clinical-trial-for-covid-19-treatments) on the WHO website—last updated on July 6, 2020—says:

> The interim Solidarity results are now being readied for peer-reviewed publication.

And that is the last I heard of it. I searched Google and PubMed but could not find the trial results.

What is the current status of the trial? Are the results out yet? If not, when can we expect them?

Comment: Are you familiar with clinicaltrials.gov? If not, you should familiarize yourself. The Solidarity project seems to be multiple, independent trials conducted in multiple countries. It doesn't seem to be a single trial. Have a look at [this](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=solidarity&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=). There are two trials that seem to be relevant to your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks for the link, that's a useful website. :) But it does not fully answer my question. There are at least 21 countries participating in this study (see https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/global-research-on-novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov/solidarity-clinical-trial-for-covid-19-treatments) clinicaltrials.gov does not have information on all of them.

Comment: @CareyGregory Also, whether Solidarity is one big trial or a bunch of small trials is open to interpretation. I guess if all centres follow the same, standardised protocol for their study, it should be regarded as one big multicentre trial. Though I don't know how much uniformity there REALLY is among the study centres. (The official WHO position is clear: it is one trial.)

Comment: That's why it was only a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The interim results of the Solidarity trial are now out: see https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2023184.